# Whats the difference between the tag "optimization" and the tag "language-performance"? Should they be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

Whats the difference between [optimization](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) and [language-performance](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-performance)? Should they be merged?

The "optimization" tag has the following tag wiki:

> Use this tag for questions about efficient compilation or execution of a programming language, including in a virtual machine, or language features that facilitate more efficient code generation or execution for interpreters

The "language-performance" tag has no wiki, but they seem like the same thing. So, what's the difference between them and should they merged?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I have burninated [language-performance](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-performance) and retagged all questions to [optimization](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization). Could a moderator please make them tag synonyms though?

Answer (score 4):

I agree that these are unclear and perhaps redundant.

Skimming over the [tags by name](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=name) for those related to performance, I spot these:

- [branch-prediction](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/branch-prediction)
- [build-time](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/build-time)
- [inlining](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inlining)
- [language-performance](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-performance)
- [optimization](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)
- [runtime](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/runtime)
- [runtime-performance](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/runtime-performance)
- [tail-call-optimization](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tail-call-optimization)

It seems to me that they can be grouped along two axes: by topic (design, implementation, ergonomics, usage, &c.) and by breadth (general or specific).

- [runtime-performance](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/runtime-performance) is a **general design** tag about the **quality of results** of a compiler.

  - [language-performance](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-performance) is also a general design tag about dynamic performance, where the questions aren’t obviously distinct from [runtime-performance](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/runtime-performance), so I think they should be merged.
- [optimization](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) is a **general implementation** tag about specific optimisations (to wit, compiler passes) meant to improve **quality of results**. It includes these as specific instances:

  - [branch-prediction](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/branch-prediction)
  - [inlining](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inlining)
  - [tail-call-optimization](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tail-call-optimization)
- There seems to be no **general implementation** tag for factors related to the **quality of implementation** of a compiler, that is, its static performance.

  - However, I think [build-time](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/build-time) would be a specific instance of that class.
- [runtime](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/runtime) was less clear to me, so I looked at the questions.

  - It has two questions ([q/2122](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/2122/54), [q/2121](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/2121/54)) using it in the attributive sense of “at runtime” (following the tag description). I think the tag could be removed from these.
  - There is also one question ([q/287](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/287/54)) with the noun sense of “a runtime”, which I think could be retagged with [virtual-machine](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine).

A complication with this way of organising things is that an interpreter could be treated as both a compiler and a virtual machine. However, at the moment the vast majority of [interpreter](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreter) questions are about general design and implementation considerations, and not directly about performance, so I will leave that for another time.

Answer (score 0):

My first impression, based only on the tag names, was:

- [optimization](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization): improvements to the efficiency of a specific compiler or interpreter.
- [language-performance](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-performance): comparison of two or more languages with respect to their inherent efficiencies.

For instance, the first could be a question about implementing tail-recursion within a compiler, while the second could be about which language would be best for a specific application.

The fundamental problem underlying this question though, is that tags get created without any description.